# UnauthorizedAccessException - Server's access denied to file directory

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, active-directory, file-permissions, file-access

I'm having an UnauthorizedAccessException error, while the application on the server is trying to read a XML document on other machine.

The code:

```
private void generateNewXml()
    {

        string filePath = (@"\\IP_LocationA\Folder\DocumentA.xml");
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();

        text = text.Replace("TextA", "TextB");

        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(text);

        xdoc.Save(@"\\IP_LocationB\Folder\DocumentB.xml");

    }
```

The error:

[UnauthorizedAccessException: Acess to  '\IP_LocationB\Folder\DocumentA.xml' was denied.]

Note: I did translate the error message from my language, so it may be different from the standard english version.

Any ideas on how to solve this ? 
Could be that User permissions with user ASPNET must be configured on the app-server-machine (IP_LocationA) and on the file-server-machine (IP_LocationB) ?